# Excel bar chart: show only capline / end

Tags: excel, customization, bar-chart

For a bar or column chart, is there a way to show only the "cap" of the bar? It's easy to set "No fill" and show only the border, but I can't find a way to isolate the border and show only the end, not the sides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to a different chart type. The error bars won't work, since a column chart only shows vertical error bars, which cannot be styled to run horizontally.

Change the chart type to a line chart with markers. Select a marker that looks like a - sign or use a picture for the marker. Format the line to be invisible. That leaves the marker only.

Screenshot shows chart before line has been formatted away.

[image]

Another option: add a column to your data, populate with a very small value. Then create a stacked column chart. Format the lower column to have no line and no fill, then only the stacked column will remain visible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about setting fill to `none`, line to `none`, and error bars to `display: both` and `end style: cap` with an error amount fixed to `0.0`?

Comment: Column charts have vertical error bars only. Horizontal bar charts have horizontal error bars only. This won't fly.